# Use Dockerfile ARG to determine FROM platform

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to pass in an optional argument to my docker file to determine the platform. If the platform is not available, I want docker to use the docker defaults.

Here is an example dockerfile that has a required argument:

```
ARG DOCKER_PLATFORM
FROM --platform=${DOCKER_PLATFORM} python:3.9-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client

...etc
```

Here is what I actually want to do:

```
ARG DOCKER_PLATFORM=
IF ${DOCKER_PLATFORM != ""
   FROM --platform=${DOCKER_PLATFORM} python:3.9-buster
ELSE:
   FROM python:3.9-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client

...etc
```

Can I have an conditional in docker? Is there anther way to remove this conditional?

Docker "FROM" docs that explain the `--platform` flag: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from
Note that `$BUILDPLATFORM` evaluates to an empty string, which is not an acceptable item to pass into --platform. I suppose that means I am not using BuildKit.

Comment: I do not understand what benefit the 2nd solution would have over the first. Please [edit] the post and clarify.

Comment: The first solution is a required argument for the dockerfile. The second is an optional argument for the dockerfile. The optional argument allows the user to specify what the platform would be only when they want too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker provides several [Automatic platform ARGs in the global scope](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope), which include a `BUILDPLATFORM` and a `TARGETPLATFORM`.  In principle you could use one of these as a default value

```sh
ARG DOCKER_PLATFORM=$TARGETPLATFORM
FROM --platform=$DOCKER_PLATFORM python:3.9
```

However, the [default `FROM --platform`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) is the target platform, and the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) `--platform` option sets this.  So rather than using a custom `ARG` here, it may be enough for you to use the default platform

```sh
# without a --platform option
FROM python:3.9
```

and if you do need an alternate platform, specify it when you build

```sh
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 ...
```

> I am not using BuildKit.

[BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) has been a non-experimental option since Docker 18.09; if it's not on by default, try setting an environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` when you `docker build`.

Comment: I can't seem to get the `ARG DOCKER_PLATFORM=$TARGETPLATFORM` to work. You are probably right that this "should" be available, but I haven't figured why `$TARGETPLATFORM` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use `TARGETPLATFORM` -- or any other built-in `ARG`, you must (re)declare the `ARG` as shown below. Not sure why, but this is indeed required.

```
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
ARG DOCKERPLATFORM=$TARGETPLATFORM
FROM --platform=$DOCKER_PLATFORM python:3.9
```

Hardly seems worth it to create another argument (i.e., `DOCKERPLATFORM`) when `TARGETPLATFORM` is already available and will serve the same purpose.